# Multer not storing large excel file in disk

Tags: node.js, excel, multer

I am trying to upload excel file with 250000 rows with multer in nodejs. I am able to upload file with 50000 rows successfully but when upload file with 250000 rows which is 7.3 MB in size. My code is below--

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, env.uploadPath)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var servFileName = Date.now()+'_'+file.originalname;//Work same as +new Date();
        //cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
        cb(null, servFileName)
    }
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage,
                limits: { fileSize: 10000000 },
                fileFilter : function(req, file, callback) { //file filter
                    // if (['xls','xlsx'].indexOf(file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length-1]) === -1) {
                    //     return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
                    // }
                    //matching extension after filename
                    console.log("multer console 1");
                    var regex = new RegExp(/.(?=xlsx|xls|xlsx.zip|xls.zip)/);
                    if(regex.exec(file.originalname)){
                      callback(null, true);
                    }else{
                      return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
                    }
                }
            }).single('file');

module.exports = upload;
```

I am not able to find out where is the problem. Please help.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set some value to maximum size, using:

```
var upload = multer({
  limits: { fileSize: YOUR_MAX_SIZE},
   ....
})
```